# How to submit multiple forms with dojo xhr?

Tags: javascript, ajax, forms, dojo

I'm trying to find a way how to submit multiple forms with ajax in one xhr.post call with dojo.
The documentation at the bottom of [this page](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dojo/_base/xhr.html#example-1-dojo-xhrget-and-form-submission) says:

> In fact, the attribute “form:” could be set on each node, not only on
>   form nodes. If your page contains more than one form and these forms
>   are enclosed with a div- or span-tag, then you’re able to submit all
>   these forms, if you set “form:” to the surrounding div- or span-tag.

Specifiying the id of e.g. a div that contains multiple forms as the "form" attribute in an xhr call does not work:

```
xhr.post({
    form: "idOfDivThatSurroundsManyForms",
    ...
});
```

It fails in domForm.formToObject, that really expects a form node (or id) which contains an elements attribute.

Is this part of the documentation just wrong or am do I miss something?

Do you have any ideas how to easily combine multiple forms into one xhr call in other ways?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the documentation is wrong and your observation is correct, `form` attribute is sent to `formToObject` as argument..

Here's a workaround:

```
require(["dojo/_base/xhr", "dojo/query", "dojo/_base/lang", "dojo/dom-form"], function (xhr, query, lang, domForm) {

  var mergedForms = {}
  query('form', 'idOfDivThatSurroundsManyForms').forEach( function(form) {
        lang.mixin(mergedForms, domForm.formToObject(form));
  } );
  xhr.post( {

    content: mergedForms
  } );

});
```

Comment: note, that if any `input`'s has identical `name`'s, the last declared (in DOM) will take prescedence. Previous values are overwritten